# Varying number of definitions in a variadic template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, variadic-templates

I recently thought of a problem. Let's say there is a variadic template like this one:

```
template <typename... Types>
class example
{
   //something
};
```

Now what I want to achieve is that when I create an object of `example<int, double, float>`, this template instance will be compiled:

```
class example<int, double, float>
{
    int int_array[5];
    double double_array[5];
    float float_array[5];
}
```

And when I create an object of `example<char, long, myClass2, myClass3>`, this instance of the class template will be generated:

```
class example<char, long, myClass2, myClass3>
{
    char char_array[5];
    long long_array[5];
    myClass2 myClass2_array[5];
    myClass3 myClass3_array[5];
}
```

So basically, for each variadic list of template parameters, repeat an action for every of the type name passed. In my example, I declared a 5-element array for each type passed to the variadic template. The names don't have to be "type_array", it can be anything, as long as I can do an action (like declaring a variable) for each of the type passed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... I suppose you can use inheritance

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct wrp
 { T a[5]; };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct example : public wrp<Ts>...
 { };

int main()
 {
   example <int, float, std::string>  e0;

   e0.wrp<int>::a[0] = 1;
   e0.wrp<float>::a[0] = 1.1f;
   e0.wrp<std::string>::a[0] = "1.11";

   std::cout << e0.wrp<int>::a[0] << std::endl;         // print 1
   std::cout << e0.wrp<float>::a[0] << std::endl;       // print 1.1
   std::cout << e0.wrp<std::string>::a[0] << std::endl; // print 1.11
 }
```

Comment: Did you test the code, does it work? (I don't have a compiler/ide at my reach now, and I am curious)

Comment: @KKZiomek - modified the example adding three prints and, yes, compile and works; with g++ (4.9.2) and with clang++ (3.5)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I looked for!